# Customized popup in Openlayers

Tags: popup, openlayers

I have done point layer overlay with openlayer. Whenever i click any point, its showing me all the data of the table in popup. How to control amount of data in the popup?

Code is:

```
....
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/layername/wms',  // geoserver point layer 
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "ABCD", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });
    map.addControl(info);
    info.activate();
```

Screenshot of current popup is

([image: popup])

I just want location_name and some html content in popup. How to do that?

Comment: The `getfeatureinfo` event object of `WMSGetFeatureInfo` has a `features` property; you're currently using `event.text` directly, I'm assuming this is what contains the formatted HTML table that gets displayed (sorry, I could not find a working `WMSGetFeatureInfo` example online). If `event.features` property contains the raw data, you could manually iterate over all returned records and render the results yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply but want some profound information as if how to use it inside popup.framecloud

Comment: Try this: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/GetFeatureInfo